# Identifying chip used in motion-sensing light

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to draw out a schematic by probing a PCB for a motion-sensing LED light, and I see this 14-pin (SOT-14?) chip shown below. The manufacturer seems to be [MicrOne](https://www.microne.com.cn/en/), but their page for the [ME9101](http://www.microne.com.cn/en/ProductDetail.aspx?id=79) chip doesn't match, showing that it has 21 GPIO pins while this chip only has 14 pins.

This chip seems to be connected to 2 other subcircuits -- one signal from a chip that detects touch on a touchpad, and another to a passive IR sensor. I'm also not sure if the symbol right next to the 9 is actually a 1, 7, or other symbol. I assume its purpose is a microcontroller but would appreciate any tips on identifying this chip. I've read another answer on how to begin identifying chips, but am still relatively new -- I'm not sure what to search for aside from the markings I see + "microcontroller". Thanks!
[image: magnified chip in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Microne ME9101 as you suspected. The line about the 21 GPIOs in the english page is just an error, they probably swapped the numbers and it should read 12. It also says 12 GPIOs further down the page.

I couldn't find a datasheet, but you can see the packages they offer [here](http://www.microne.com.cn/en/Products.aspx?cid=35):

[image]

SOP14 matches with the chip in your picture.

Comment: I had to make an account just to look at the datasheet... here it is: http://www.microne.com.cn/UploadFiles/Files2/20180703/20180703144336.pdf